# Gradient Color to MPAndroid Barchart

Tags: android, bar-chart, gradient, mpandroidchart

I want to use my custom gradient for MPAndroid Bar chart. I have made my custom drawable color as below:

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip
        android:clipOrientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#00AEEE"
                android:centerColor="#0086CA"
                android:endColor="#315AA6"
                android:angle="90" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

I tried assigning it to my barchart as follows:
barDataSet.setColor(R.drawable.gradient_color);
Another issue is that I want to display Right Side YAxis label from 0-10.9 . but it is dynamically changing to points close to minimum, i mean to say, if my minimum result is 6 den it skips numbers below 6

[image]

But it is not what i want. I want my result to be like below:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code it might be close enough:

```
 Paint mPaint = barChart.getRenderer().getPaintRender(); mPaint.setShader(new   
  SweepGradient(350,120,Color.parseColor("#FFF212"),Color.parseColor("#FCE121")));
```

Comment: Not Working for Latest version MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, you will get a better result.

```
paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0,0,0,10,new   int[]{Color.parseColor("#00AEEE"),Color.parseColor("#0086CA"),Color.parseColor("#315AA6")},new float[]{0,2,2}, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
```

Comment: What's `paint`?

Answer (score 1):

New version supports gradient -

```
val barDataSet = BarDataSet(entries, "Days")
val startColor =
        ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.colorPrimary)
    val endColor = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),  
                   R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
barDataSet.setGradientColor(startColor, endColor)
```

if you want to use more gradients just make a list of GradientColor and pass it to barDataSet.setGradientColors() function